# POWER BI KPI Visualisation Text Value

Tags: text, data-visualization, powerbi, dax, kpi

I would like to display `n.a.` or `available quarterly` (Value and Target) in the KPI card visualization, keeping in mind that in the column of my table I can have either Percentage or Integer

The result can be either a Value `n.a.` with Target `n.a.` or Value `47%` with a Target `n.a.`, therefore the will be any distance between them

The goal is to display a text that motivates the absence of value in the period, and not having an empty field

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMDiE.png)

Is it possible?

Comment: I'd suggest including the ISBLANK() function in your formulas

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong
The data in the column are coming from an Excel file and there aren´t any formula

The final result is a KPI card with the comparison between the value and the Target, and a Slicer for the Period

I would like to show for each period the Value vs Target but when a Target or a Values is missing I would like to see "n.a." or "available quarterly"

I tried with a formula but the KPI visualization is not taking a formula column

Comment: @Sid29 I ve done everything but I still have the Calculated Column "Value Final" as a Text Type and I cannot Add it in the KPI Visual

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into Edit Queries and create a conditional column called as "Validation" which calls out as Applicable only when both the Target and Value is not empty.

[image: Conditional Column Creation]

2. So once the conditional column is created. Create the Value and Target Calculated column that can be used in the visual as below.

> Value Final = IF(Table1[Validation]="Applicable",FORMAT(Table1[%
>   Value],"Percent"),"Not Available")
>
> Target Final =
>   IF(Table1[Validation]="Applicable",FORMAT(Table1[Target],"Percent"),"Not
>   Available")

The key here in these calculated columns are the usage of `FORMAT`

Here is a case of where the Target is not present -

[image: PowerBI Target and Value]

let me know, if this doesn't help your requirement.

Comment: I would like to see "n.a." or "available quarterly" in the KPI card instead of (Blank)
I cannot add a table
The purpose is to create a page with all the KPI card with different KPI ( I have several columns with Value and Target for each KPI)

Comment: @AndreV updated the answer. 2 data types in a visual isn't something that PowerBI supports as much as I know. But you can put it out on 2 different cards separately (one for target and one for value).